# ArrayList tries to access one index too many

Tags: c#, arraylist

I get an error with the following code since my counter increments itself 1 time too many, andI dont understand why.

Code:

```
...private static int counter = 0;

protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendWord();
            object o = wordList[counter];
            LabelWord.Text = o.ToString();
            if (counter < wordList.Count)
            {
                counter++;
            }
         }
```

If I use `counter < wordList.Count -1)` it doesnt give me an error, but it also doesnt load the last word in my list. What am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Comment: try to use `counter<= wordlist.count-1`

Comment: I have already tried that

Comment: More context is necessary. Where are the contents of `wordList` mutated? Also, why are you using an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code like this:

```
if (counter < wordList.Count)
{
    object o = wordList[counter++];
    LabelWord.Text = o.ToString();
}
```

This will not give you `OufOfRange` exception, and should return the all items.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with you code if

```
 if (counter < wordList.Count)
            {
                counter++;
            }
```

let say `count` is 10

the list is from 0 to 9 index

in the last loop when counter is 9 ...the condition is true and it increaments by one and it terminates the loop

i case 2  `if (counter < wordList.Count-1)`   it correct ,,, increaments until 8 and terminates

use this one

`if (counter <=wordList.Count-1`)

Comment: you still need to include the `object o = wordList[counter++];` statement inside the IF block or may encounter the Out of Range exception when `counter == wordList.Count`